# Run shell script after Docker daemon starts

Tags: macos, docker, shell-script

My docker daemon starts on user login and I want to run a script once it is ready.

I know about `open -a Docker` but the command returns while the Docker is starting.

How can I make sure that docker is ready inside a bash script started by a launchd agent?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `docker version`, which returns exit status of 1 if Docker daemon is not running.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uncomment next line if you want to start Docker from this script.
# open -a Docker

# Loop until 'docker version' exits with 0.
until docker version > /dev/null 2>&1
do
  sleep 1
done
```

The script above will execute `docker version` every second until it exits with 0, meaning docker daemon is ready.

Comment: `docker version` isn't returning status 1 anymore. But the above can be easily modified to use `docker ps` instead